# PL/SQL Help to check for specific values in specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query. I have 1 column `user_auto` with `234` value.
I want to find which table is using this Column and with specific value.

I have done how many table is using this column.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%user_auto%'
ORDER BY  table_name;
```

Now I want this table with `user_auto = 234` have change the value.
Means User_auto value is 234. want all detail about this user?

Comment: So you mean you have a query that uses a column from a table, and rather than looking at the query to determine which table it is, you want to search for the column in the system tables? Fine. Have you tried anything else? The last part of your question is quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```
SQL> desc foo1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_AUTO                                          NUMBER

SQL> desc foo2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_AUTO                                          NUMBER

SQL> select * From foo1;

 USER_AUTO
----------
       123
      1234

SQL> select * From foo2;

 USER_AUTO
----------
       234

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    v_val varchar2(3) := '234';
  3    v_cnt pls_integer;
  4  begin
  5    for r_tab in (select table_name, column_name
  6                    from all_tab_columns
  7                   where column_name = 'USER_AUTO'
  8                   order by 1)
  9    loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line('Found table ' || r_tab.table_name || ' with column '||r_tab.column_name);
 11      execute immediate 'begin select count(*) into :b0 from '
 12                        || r_tab.table_name
 13                        || ' where rownum = 1 and ' || r_tab.column_name || ' = :b1;'
 14                        || 'end;' using out v_cnt, v_val;
 15      if (v_cnt = 1)
 16      then
 17        dbms_output.put_line(chr(9)||'row found for ' || v_val);
 18      else
 19        dbms_output.put_line(chr(9)||'no row found for ' || v_val);
 20      end if;
 21    end loop;
 22  end;
 23  /
Found table FOO1 with column USER_AUTO
        no row found for 234
Found table FOO2 with column USER_AUTO
        row found for 234

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi Dazzal, Thanks for reply.. Can you send me PROCEDURE for this.

Comment: sql server? you've tagged this question as Oracle. i've retagged it for you.